# l'expression "s'y informe"

Tags: expressions

Que veut dire l'expression "s'y informe" dans ce contexte :

> La sexualité humaine est un phénomène social total : tout s'y joue, s'y exprime, s'y informe dès le commencement des sociétés.

Answer (score 2):

Le *phénomène social total* est la clef de compréhension :
Il est le *lieu imaginaire* où toutes les pensées s'agitent, se découvrent, se développent, se contredisent, s'expérimentent, se résorbent.

Dans cet *endroit immatériel* dont on parle, (le 'phénomène social total', ce 'lieu imaginaire' qui n'a pas d'adresse précise ailleurs que dans les cerveaux concernés, et donc dans la prise de conscience de la sexualité), on *s*'y *informe* de ce qu'il s'*y* passe, c'est-à-dire que l'on cherche des informations que l'on ne peut connaître autre part ; dans l'exemple cité, la sexualité informe chaque personne qu'y s'y intéresse de ce qu'elle est en réalité.

Comment: Il est d'usage de motiver les votes négatifs afin de permettre l'amélioration des réponses, merci :)

Answer (score 2):

Informer c'est faire savoir quelque chose à quelqu'un, le porter à sa connaissance, le lui apprendre... On parle donc d'un transfert de connaissance. Comme dans la phrase "*Tel fait informe ma décision*"

Ici, par sa tournure de phrase, l'auteur affirme que la sexualité constitue un intrant informationnel omniprésent.

Answer (score 1):

D'autres réponses s'attardent au sens et au contexte plus directement. En terme d'analyse, il s'agit simplement de verbes avec emploi pronominal réfléchi ou passif (se [jouer](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer) sur, s'[informer](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/informer), s'[exprimer](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/exprimer)) avec un emploi parfois au figuré. Le pronom *y* intercalé réfère à ce qui précède, soit la *sexualité humaine*, et pourrait être remplacé par : **par/dans/de celà**. Donc la *source* ou le *truchement*, me semble-t-il. Tout *passe par/vient de ou origine de*... la sexualité. Avec l'emploi pronominal : Toutes les choses s'expriment (se *manifestent*) *dans/par/à partir* de la sexualité humaine. *Tout s'y exprime*.